# How to include code within a p

Tags: pug

How do I include script code within a `p` element? In the below, I want to treat the `if` line as script.

```
p.
   Line 1 .... <br/>
   Line 2 .... <br/>
   if (x)
     Line 3a .... <br/>
   else
     Line 3b ..... <br/>
   Line 4 .....  <br/>
```

Or is there another way of achieving the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either of following 2 ways:

```
p.
   Line 1 .... <br/>
   Line 2 .... <br/>
   <script> //Your javascript code here 
   </script>
   Line 4 .....  <br/>
```

OR

```
p
  | Line 1
  br
  | Line 2
  if someBooleanExpression //your javascript code here
    | Line 3a
  else
    | Line 3b
```